# Should [tag:homosexuality] be separate from [tag:sexuality]?

Tags: discussion, tags

[homosexuality](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homosexuality) seems to be a strict subset of [sexuality](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sexuality). I don't really know how many questions about homosexuality to expect, but it seems like having separate tags for each orientation is unneeded. What is the typical tag behavior here? Strangely, [homosexuality](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homosexuality) has 7 questions as of this post whereas [sexuality](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sexuality) has 6. (Also, [homosexuality](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homosexuality) has a nifty blurb already. So I guess that's something.)

Answer (score 2):

I tend to agree. [Homosexuality] probably should be absorbed by [Sexuality].

Comment: One option is to edit up the sexuality tag with a list of orientations.

Comment: [homoseuxality] will never have enough topics to warant it's own tag on our site, so it should definitely be merged.

Comment: @KitSunde There's currently 200 questions, with about 40 on homosexuality. Sounds like enough to me.

Comment: @fredsbend Do you find it useful to reply to a comment that is 9 years old?

Comment: @KitSunde This comment at this time, yes. Someone made a tag edit adding [lgbt], which doesn't seem that useful to me, so I looked into the tags we have and found a few things that maybe need adjustment, which you can read about [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/55217626#55217626) or later here on meta if I decide to post. This is the only discussion I could find on why [homosexuality] is a synonym of [sexuality], and it seems the only relevant reasoning given is yours, which appears to have turned out to be wrong.